# detectChanges doesn't update async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

I am using this observable in the component

```
    this.pagedRecords$ =
        this.records$.pipe(
            map((records) => records
                .filter(rec => (!this.filterParams.stream) || rec.streamId === this.filterParams.stream)
                .filter(rec => (!this.filterParams.topicId) || rec.topicId === this.filterParams.topicId)
                .filter(rec => (!this.filterParams.date || moment.tz(rec.timestamp, rec.timezone)
                    .isSame(this.filterParams.date.original.tz(rec.timezone), 'day')))
                .slice(page * this.pagination.perPage, (page + 1) * this.pagination.perPage - 1)),
            tap((records) => {
                console.log(records);
                this.noRecordings = records.length === 0;
                this.cdr.markForCheck();
                this.cdr.detectChanges();
            }),
            repeatWhen(delay(10000)),
            takeWhile(records => records.some(rec => rec.status === 'processing') || !this.recordingsLoaded),
            tap(() => this.recordingsLoaded = true));
```

The pipe works as it is supposed to do: polls result until there are no longer items having status set to "processing"

This is how the pipe is used in the template

```
            <ng-container *ngFor="let record of (pagedRecords$|async)">

                        <audio
                            *ngIf="browser === 'Chrome' && record?.status==='completed' && (record?.url|fileExtension) === 'mp3'"
                            controls
                            controlsList="nodownload"
                            class="w100">
                            <source [src]="record?.url" type="audio/webm">
                        </audio>

                 

                        <span *ngIf="record?.status==='processing'">
                            Recording processing
                        </span>

                        <div *ngIf="record?.status==='unprocessed'">
                            <div class="button smallest unset-width" (click)="processRecording(record)">
                                Process to download
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <span *ngIf="browser !== 'Chrome'">Not supported in your browser</span>
                   
            </ng-container>
```

Even when polling ends, template status won't get updated (and I saw that status is set to "completed" or "unprocessed" on all items by console log).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get an exact understanding of how your code is expected to work, so I'm just guessing here, but note that by default `takeWhile` won't emit the value the caused the condition to return `false`.

So once `records$` starts emitting only items with `status != 'processing'` `pagedRecords$` will complete without emitting them. In order to emit those values you need to set the `inclusive` option to `true` on `takeWhile`:

```
takeWhile(records => records.some(rec => rec.status === 'processing') || !this.recordingsLoaded, true)
```